# How to show different timestamp

Tags: posts, date-time, timestamp

I would like to show published time "Posted 4:15pm" for the first 24 hours, after 24hours show full published date and time "September 27, 2016 at 4:15pm"

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is this being shown? May you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
// See if the post is older than 24 hours.
if ( get_post_time() <= strtotime( '-1 day' ) ) {
  echo 'Published more than 24 hours ago.';
} else {
  echo 'Published within the last 24 hours.';
}
```

Comment: @choche if my answer solved your question, please accept it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So far :

```
function ci_posted_on() {
$time_string = '<time itemprop="datePublished" content="%2$s" class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
    $time_string = '<time itemprop="datePublished" content="%2$s" class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time itemprop="dateModified" content="%4$s" class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
}

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
);

$time_posted = esc_html( get_the_time() );
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U');

$posted_on = sprintf(
    _x( '%s', 'post date', 'ci' ),
    '' . $time_string . ''
);

if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) :
   the_modified_time('g:i a'); 
else :
   echo ' . $posted_on . ' at ' . $time_posted . ';
```

This is working but using modified date, i want if published date is less than 24 hours show time and after 24 hours show date and time